# Mix covariance between Kotlin and Scala

Tags: scala, covariance

I have a Kotlin class

```
class Result<out ResultType>(val value: ResultType, val msg:String?)
```

which I use in Scala with no problem, until I tried to write something like this

```
def processResult(result: Result[AnyRef]) = ...

processResult( new Result[Int](4) )
```

last line doesn't compile because

```
type mismatch;
   found   : Result[Int]
   required: Result[AnyRef]
```

Now, I expect that Scala will not manage to understand Kotlin's 'out' definition, but I don't see anyway to write processResult() in a way that will not force me to write explicit casts every time.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You have two issues here.

1/ In Scala, `Int` is not a subtype of `AnyRef` (reference types) but of `AnyVal` (all values types). `Any` being the supertype of both.

You'd have the same error in pure Scala code:

```scala
case class Result[+ResultType](value: ResultType)

def processResult(result: Result[AnyRef]) = ???

processResult(new Result[Int](4))
```

Using `Any` solves this first issue. This might not be encouraged though as you kinda lose any information about the underlying type.

You could rather add the type to the method itself:

```scala
def processResult[T](result: Result[T]) = ???
```

It depends on what you expect to do.

2/ Indeed there's no interop between Kotlin `out` and Scala `+/-`. That I don't think there's an easy way around it unfortunately.

Edit: as suggested by Luis in the comments, a wrapper class + using `.asInstanceOf` in the wrapper class could be a solution.

Comment: Probably the best is to create a custom wrapper or `opaque type` that is covariant, and use casting _(`asInstanceOf` )_ on the implementation.

Comment: I didn't understand that. What wrapper do I need to use around what?

Comment: Gaël J - You're right about issue #1. I stripped down my code for this question. My original classes are much more complex.